# Microsoft Bing Event Tracking in Next.js

Tags: next.js, bing

I see there is an example for ad tracking for Google tag manager and with Facebook pixel on Next.js examples site - I cannot find an example for Microsoft Universal Event tracking either at Next.js or searching for a solution. Can someone please point me in the right direction.  Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is a place to ask code snippets. Please read guideline here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Actually, I have the same question. Could you find any solution for this?